# nrow returns null value for only one row in R

Tags: r

When I subset just one row of a matrix and pass that to nrow as `nrow(x[1,])` or `nrow(x[2,])` it returns a `NULL` value instead of `1`.

However if I subset more than one row then `nrow(x[1:2,])` returns `2` which is a correct value.

Need help on how to handle cases like `nrow(x[i,])`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share `dput(x)` so that we know what is the structure of the dataframe?

Comment: It's a matrix, that's the problem. `nrow( M[ 1, ] )` returns a vector that doesn't have rows.

Comment: Bad expression `M[ 1, ]` is a vector, check `str( M[ 1, ] )` - that's why `nrow( M[ 1, ] )` returns NULL.

Comment: @RonakShah , it does not work for even a simple 3X3 matrix, with all elements as 1. Here is the dput(x): structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))

Comment: @vaettchen, Thanks for your input.  Actually I want to call a function which works for any subset irrespective of number of rows. In that fuction there is a for loop which I want to use for each subsetted row. for (i in seq_len(nrow(x))){......} Any suggestions on how to make this for loop work for any number of rows.

Comment: You may hae to introduce in your loop something like `if( length( nrow( M[ 1, ] ) ) < 1 ) i <- 1` or so - if not somebody more knowledgeable comes up with a better idea

Comment: Try `x[1, ,drop=FALSE]`. It's a common noob error. Read `?'['`. I'm too lazy to search for a duplicate and would know for sure that it was correctly identified because YOU HAVEN'T OFFERED ANY DATA OR CODE.

Comment: @42 that helps!

Comment: Whether it helps will depend on whether the questioner reads it and acts.

Comment: @42 Thanks for the tip. It helps.  Others who responded .Thanks for your inputs too. Somehow I am finding R rather unintuitive as compared to Python. For straightforward problems we  have to do some convoluted implementations.

Comment: Dropping dimensions without warning is one of those R infelicities that was inherited from S. I suspect R/S are even less strongly typed than Python. R factors are also the cause of many unintuitive errors. If you want stronger typing use C, a language only slightly older than S, both developed at Bell Labs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NCOL()` and `NROW()`, they treat vectors *as 1-column matrix*, i.e

```
x <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L)) 
x
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    1
```

Now, as you point out `nrow(x[1,])` and `nrow(x[2,])` return `NULL`

```
nrow(x[1,])
#> NULL
nrow(x[2,])
#> NULL
```

but,

```
NCOL(x[1,])
#> [1] 1
NROW(x[1,])
#> [1] 3
```

You could also make the object a tibble, but I guess you don't want to go there with a matrix. Regardless,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)

z <- x %>% as_tibble() 

nrow(z[1,])
#> [1] 1
ncol(z[1,])
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `drop = FALSE` in subsetting the matrix, which provides R from dropping the matrix class:

```r
(m <- matrix(1, 3, 3))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1    1
#> [3,]    1    1    1
class(m[1, ])
#> [1] "numeric"
class(m[1, , drop = FALSE])
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
```

Then `nrow()` returns the desired result:

```r
nrow(m[1, , drop = FALSE])
#> [1] 1
nrow(m[2, , drop = FALSE])
#> [1] 1
```